# navigate to other screen from alert message

Tags: react-native, authentication, alert, touch-id

I'm new to react native and I'm building an application which will authenticate the user using the fingerprint and will navigate if successful to next screen through the button displayed on alert message. But I'm not able to navigate. 
I'm getting the alert message popup along with a button on the popup. But the button functionality (***Alert.alert('Authenticated Successfully','', [{text: 'Proceed', onPress:() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Main')}] )***) is not working as expected.

Here is the code snippet of the particular screen:-

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground, Alert } from 'react-native';
import TouchID from 'react-native-touch-id';

export default class FingerPrintScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground style={{ flex: 1, width: null, height: null, resizeMode: 'cover'}} source={{ uri: 'https://jooinn.com/images/white-clouds-25.jpg' }}>
        <View style={stylesLogin.LoginScreenView}>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', top: '10%', fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: 30, color: '#0143B8', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Authenticate using Fingerprint.</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.55} style={ stylesLogin.HomeButton } onPress={() => this.props.navigation.popToTop('Home')}>
            <Text style={{ textAlign:'center', fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: 30, color: '#FFFFFF', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Go to Home</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.55} style={stylesLogin.FingerPrintButton} onPress={this.clickHandler}>
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: 30, color: '#FFFFFF', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Click Here to Authenticate using Fingerprint</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
  clickHandler() {
    TouchID.isSupported()
    .then( authenticate() )
    .catch( error => {
      Alert.alert( 'Biometric not supported' )
    })
  }
}
  
function authenticate() {
  return TouchID.authenticate()
  .then( success => {
      Alert.alert('Authenticated Successfully',' Click Proceed to Continue', [{text: 'Proceed', onPress:() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Main')}] )
    })
    .catch(error => {
      Alert.alert(error.message);
  })
}
```

im not able to do so because the authenticate function is located outside the component .
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

**Since your function is outside the component you will not get the props there, please pass the props to the function as shown in the below code.**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground, Alert } from 'react-native';
import TouchID from 'react-native-touch-id';

export default class FingerPrintScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground style={{ flex: 1, width: null, height: null, resizeMode: 'cover'}} source={{ uri: 'https://jooinn.com/images/white-clouds-25.jpg' }}>
        <View style={stylesLogin.LoginScreenView}>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', top: '10%', fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: 30, color: '#0143B8', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Authenticate using Fingerprint.</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.55} style={ stylesLogin.HomeButton } onPress={() => this.props.navigation.popToTop('Home')}>
            <Text style={{ textAlign:'center', fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: 30, color: '#FFFFFF', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Go to Home</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.55} style={stylesLogin.FingerPrintButton} onPress={this.clickHandler}>
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: 30, color: '#FFFFFF', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Click Here to Authenticate using Fingerprint</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
  clickHandler() {
    TouchID.isSupported()
    .then(()=> authenticate(this.props))
    .catch( error => {
      Alert.alert('Biometric not supported' )
    })
  }
}

function authenticate(props) {
  return TouchID.authenticate()
  .then( success => {
      Alert.alert('Authenticated Successfully','', [{text: 'Proceed', onPress:() => props.navigation.navigate('Main')}] )
    })
    .catch(error => {
      Alert.alert(error.message);
  })
}
```

And if its still not working check the if the button click is working, place an alert on the button click instead of the function call.And refer make the syntax of alert correctly by refering the orginal documentation link below.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert

Comment: Yes. the alert is showing up. I tried the solution you have mentioned. It gave me an error saying cant find variable: authenticate

Comment: The button is working. But I'm getting an error ***undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation')*** when I'm implementing your code solution

Comment: I have again edited the answer you will need to bind the function, try the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You will see you can access the navigation from any component as long as you have it in the route file (stackNavigator ...).
The authentication component is your child, so you don't directly have navigation. You can verify this by doing a console.log of this.props

First and for me the best solution

The solution is very simple: If the father can access this.props.navigation you can pass it on to the child when you call the component as follows:

```
        <ChildComponent navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

Another solution, although much more convoluted, consists of the following:
First you create a function in the parent component:

```
functionPass = () => {}
```

Within this function you do this.props.navigation

Then you pass it to the child component as I told you before and there doing this.props and the name you have given you will call the function from the father but as I say I recommend the first option

Comment: I'm sorry but i wasn't able to understand the solution as I'm new to react-native. Could you please help me out by clarifying it or by making the changes in the code and upload the code snippet.
Thank You